# Вызов функции процессом в c#

Tags: c#, процесс

Следующий код запускает 2 потока одновременно (оба потока пишут в файл), но один поток d2 ждет, пока поток d1 закончит работу.

По заданию, мне нужно использовать не потоки, а процессы. Как мне реализовать использование процессов вместо потоков?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test_ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static public void d1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("d1 start");
            StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt", true);
            f.WriteLine("Строка1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            f.WriteLine("Строка2");
            f.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("d1 end");
            waitMe.Set();
        }
        static private AutoResetEvent waitMe = new AutoResetEvent( false);
        static public void d2()
        {
            waitMe.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("d2 start");
            StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt", true);
            f.WriteLine("Строка3");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            f.WriteLine("Строка4");
            f.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("d2 end"); ;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var thread1 = new Thread(() => d1());
            var thread2 = new Thread(() => d2());
            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();

            thread1.Join();
            thread2.Join();

        }
    }
}
```

На разных сайтах нашел, что можно вызвать через процесс отдельную программу.ехе, а как можно вызвать функцию процессом?

Comment: Вы понимаете что такое процесс?

Comment: @tym32167 вполне. Как можно запустить процесс, который будет исполнять функцию?

Comment: [Process.Start Метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @tym32167 в этом методе используется путь к файлу.exe  запуская и связывает его с Process. Но в моем случае у меня в том же проекте находится функция, которую я хочу запустить прямо из main() как процесс. 
Это возможно сделать?

Comment: Вы же сказали, что знаете, что такое процесс. Но судя по вашим вопросам, это не так. Попробуйте описать вашу задачу более подробно, что вы делаете, зачем и почему вам вообще нужен отдельнй процесс?

Comment: @tym32167 расписал свой вопрос подробнее. Мне нужно использовать вместо поток процессы

Comment: я думаю, вам надо 1) Написать 2 программы (по программе на поток), каждая пусть делает то же, что делает поток у вас. 2) Запустить обе программы - получите 2 процесса 3) Синхронизировать эти процессы через механизмы синхронизации на уровне ОС, например через именованные мьютекс.

Comment: @tym32167 хочу уточнить, возможно сделать в одном visual studio проекте  3 файла: file1 (1 процесс), file2 (2 процесс), file3 (запускает file1 и file2) или же только для каждого процесса сделать готовый exe файл?

Comment: чтобы запустить процесс вам все равно надо иметь какой то exe. Для ваших двух процессов этоо может быть 2 разных exe или один и тот же exe, но с разными параметрами запуска.

Comment: @tym32167 понял, спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: без проблем, на здоровье

Comment: Есть поток `Thread`, задача `Task` и процесс `Process` и между ними 3 большие разницы. Рекомендую автору изучить вопрос полностью.